# How to show image that's been given as 1-D array

Tags: python, image, numpy

So I have a file with 6 different people, each person having 2 photos (in different angles) thus there are 6 * 2 = 12 images (in B&W).

Each image is 140 (ht) x 120 (width)

When I read the file, all the info is read so I have 12 columns (corresponding to each image) and 16,800 rows (corresponding to the image size).

How do I plot the image on matplotlib ?

I tried extracting each column e.g. df.loc[:,0] and then reshaping it to (140,120). But plotting it gives some abstract art looking output instead of the face. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `result = yourArray.reshape(-1, 140, 120)` to create a 3D array containing your 2D images. You can then iterate over the image using a simple loop over the reshaped array.

Comment: Have you tried reshaping it as 120, 140 too? What does that look like? Sometimes the order arrays are flattened can be different

Comment: yeah I've tried both ways but they just give a random blot of colour. I tried reading the image directly and outputting its array for comparison but the array outputs correctly in (140,120). The values do look different though (I don't see any high values greater than 100 I think ) so I might be missing something

Comment: have you tried both row-major and column-major ordering?

Answer (score -1):

I've solved it. I think it was a bug/glitch.

So I tried with plt.imshow() and plt.show() but it did not work.
I then tried various methods plt.plot() <- which was giving me the weird colour output.

Eventually, going back to plt.imshow() somehow worked